# Multiple monitors : Gnome opens windows minimized

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, gnome, multiple-monitors

Using 3 screens, windows are often opened minimized (full application like Terminator, or menus in Google Chrome, Intellij Idea) :

[image]

How can I prevent this behaviour ? (Seen in 18.04 an 20.04)